# group a validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

hi on new in rails and starting to develop my application which is a online reservation 
im just wondering if there is a way in Ruby on rails to group a validation

ei.
i want to validate the date first in the database and check for its presence and what are the timeStart and endTime entries in that particular date and validate its uniqueness(timeStart and endTime) base on the date? is it possible in validation or do i have to make a controller or method for it?

sorry for my bad english
my Reservation database is:

```
0           id          INTEGER     1                       1         
1           lname       varchar(25  1                       0         
2           fname       varchar(25  1                       0         
3           contactnum  integer     1                       0         
4           email       varchar(10  1                       0         
5           date        date        1           '2012-03-0  0         
6           timeStart   time        1           '---
:hour  0         
7           timeEnd     time        1           '---
:hour  0         
8           numGuest    integer     0           5           0         
9           totalCost   decimal(2)  0                       0         
10          confirm     boolean     0           'f'         0         
11          created_at  datetime    0                       0         
12          updated_at  datetime    0                       0
```

Comment: Just to clarify:  are you asking "Can I use validations to ensure that a reservation does not conflict with other reservations in the database?"  If that's the case, I don't think the built in validations are going to help you (since they are generally checking the validity of a single model), but you could create a before_save method that does whatever validation you want...

Comment: @MarcTalbot yes close to that i want to check the date first and check its timeend and timestarts from that date.because my reservation can book a record 2 or more entries in a day only not same time

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking up Rails Validations? What you want is the uniqueness validation. However, sometimes you will have to write your own validation, depending on if there isn't a built in validation method.

The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) will help you out. I've linked right to the part about the uniqueness method.

Comment: yes i already what i want is to check the date first because in my application its possible to have 2 reservation in a day =/ thanks for the fast reply btw :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty easy thing to do, I'm assuming your model is called reservation:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :date_and_times_are_unique

  def date_and_times_are_unique
    if Reservation.where(date: date, timeStart: timeStart, timeEnd: timeEnd).any?
      errors.add(:base, "The reservation date and time combination must be unique")
    end
  end
end
```

This is a custom validator which simply makes sure that there are no other records that have the same date, timeStart and timeEnd, and I think does what you want it to do.

Comment: uhm they can have the same date but not same time in a same date,i want to check the date first and check its timeend and timestarts from that date.because my reservation can book a record 2 or more entries in a day only not same time.im a day old in rails

Comment: RIght, that validation will only fail if there is already a reservation with the same date, timeStart, and timeEnd.  If it only had 2 of those things in common, or if it just had the same Date, it would still be valid.